# in mkmapview didSelectAnnotationView use can only touch a custom marker once, how to clear

Tags: ios5, touch, mkmapview

I have custom markers in a map view. When the user touches one the app moves to another page. If the user returns to the map and touches the same item again

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
```

is not called until you touch somewhere in the map and then touch the marker again.

I tried deselecting the annotation view but the docs say not too, and in any case it didn't work.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Can you show the code you used to deselect the annotation?

Comment: I tried view.selected = NO but that's not allowed and doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of setting `view.selected` directly which the documentation says not to do, call the `deselectAnnotation:animated:` method instead:

```
[mapView deselectAnnotation:view.annotation animated:YES];
```

By the way, for the reverse, there's the `selectAnnotation:animated:` method.

Comment: Argh, must need new glasses. Thanks, I missed that one.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to recognize taps on the annotation view.

Comment: Would that allow me to capture the tap outside of the normal map view didSelectAnnotationView?